# Raspberry Pi doesn't boot after using 5v pin

Tags: pi-3b+, boot-issues

I recently got a Raspberry Pi 3B+, and it booted just fine and worked properly. I also had a 12v latch solenoid (the solenoid worked when I connected it to a 9v battery). I connected one end of the solenoid to a 9v battery, and the other one to the 5v pin (physical pin number 2) of my Raspberry Pi, then I wasn't getting any HDMI display, and when I tried rebooting the Pi, it wouldn't boot. I've waited for a few days and tried again, and even reinstalled the OS on my SD card, but it's still not booting (no green light), but the red light stays on.

How can I fix my Raspberry Pi? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is dead Jim.

Comment: So there's nothing I can do to fix my Pi? Like it's completely dead?

Comment: Solenoids, motor and relays are inductive and create a inrush current that will kill your Raspberry Pi, see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/247297/inductor-in-rush-current

Comment: `connected one end of the solenoid to a 9v battery, and the other one to the 5v pin` ... how did you complete the circuit? ... in other words, where did you connect the other battery terminal? ... which battery terminal was connected to the solenoid?

Comment: @jsotola The other battery terminal wasn't connected anywhere. One wire of the solenoid was to one terminal of the battery, the other wire of the solenoid was to the 5v pin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to fix it is to replace it. It will make a nice template for projects when mounting other units like it. It will give you something to practice soldering on. Put in front of your monitor to remind you not to put more than 3.3V on any Pi  GPIO. The most important thing is do not connect anything inductive (has a coil) to any GPIO or you will fry another one. There are many tutorials that will show you how to connect the PI to a solenoid. Many are in error, the pull down resistor goes from the GPIO to ground, not the gate to ground. That way you will not divide what little voltage you have down even more.

Comment: It is dead because the OP put 9V on the PMIC. Absolutely nothing to do with solenoids.